# How to pick up all the elements from a python list that meet certain criteria?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a long list of large floating point numbers:

```
lis = [0.10593584063824,... ,9.5068763787043226e-34, 9.8763787043226e-34, 8.3617950149494853e-34]
```

How can I pick into a new array all the numbers that fulfill certain criteria? For example, how can I pick up into a new list all the numbers that are `a_constant > .95`

Comment: Use filter. `a = filter(lambda x: x > 0.95, lis)`

Comment: _"...list all the numbers that are `a_constant > .95`"_ What do you mean by this? Is `a_constant` a constant or an element of the list? This is very confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> l = [0.2, 0.4, 0.5]

# Case list into numpy array type.
>>> l_arr = np.array(l)

# Returns the indices that meets the condition.
>>> np.where(l_arr > 0.3)
(array([1, 2]),)

# Returns the values that meets the condition.
>>> l_arr[np.where(l_arr > 0.3)]
array([ 0.4,  0.5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension :

```
lis = [0.10593584063824,... ,9.5068763787043226e-34, 9.8763787043226e-34, 8.3617950149494853e-34]
out = [x for x in lis if 0.65 > x > 0.95]
```

Comment: yes but what about the constant?.... is that the same as x?

Comment: what constant ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use numpy- if you are using this in a data science job.First,convert the list into a numpy array, then apply the condition and convert the numpy array back to list.

```
import numpy as np

lis = [0.10593584063824e-34,2.5068763787043226e-34,9.5068763787043226e-34, 9.8763787043226e-34, 8.3617950149494853e-34]

#Convert the list into a numpy array
np_array = np.array([[lis]])

#filter the np array and convert back to a list
new_lis = (np_array[np_array > 3.7e-34]).tolist()

[9.506876378704323e-34, 9.8763787043226e-34, 8.361795014949486e-34]
```